# Using relative xpath to scrape custom div attribute

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a few hundred URLs where I'm trying to scrape the image path for an image on a page. Each page is the same format, but the div class is unique to each page.

I want to be able to use import xml in Google sheets to scrape just the content of the data-path element.

I've tried and failed to use xpath to pull out the URLs.

```
<div class="uniqueid active" data-path="/~/media/Images/image.jpg" data-alt="Anything"></div>
```

E.g. `//div[@class='*']/@data-path"`

Example of site: https://www.cannondale.com/en/Australia/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=77d3b8fe-41f7-42b6-bf69-b5cf0ae55548&parentid=undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If div class has the pattern `"uniqueid active"`, then you can try the following XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class, "active")]/@data-path
```

Otherwise, if div class can be anything, use this query:

```
//div[@class]/@data-path
```

---

UPDATE:

I tried to get values of `data-path` attributes with *IMPORTXML*, but didn't succeed. Tried to do it using Python (`requests` and `lxml`) and it works. So probably the problem is in Google Sheets - some limitations or bugs, idk.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike, neither work, I'm wondering if Google sheets doesn't fully support xpath

Comment: If the page has dynamic content - you won't be able to extract that content with XPath. You can include at least one URL in your question, then I can see for sure.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it's the main image path I'm trying to get here: https://www.cannondale.com/en/Australia/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=77d3b8fe-41f7-42b6-bf69-b5cf0ae55548&parentid=undefined

Comment: Strange, I can see the `<div data-path="..." ...>` in response, but can't get it with *IMPORTXML* in Google Sheets.